# What is the word for inserting additional letters when pronouncing a word?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, terminology, phonology, phonetics

A while back I ran across a word that described the act of inserting additional letters or sounds when a person pronounces a word (which results in a mispronunciation).  What is the word that has this meaning?

Update:
My original example wasn't very good, but Brian Donovan provided a good example--decathlon pronounced as "decathalon" (inserting a second "a" sound where there is no "a").

Another example: hamster pronounced as "hampster"

Comment: Is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_and_intrusive_R) what you're looking for?

Comment: For another example, I once cringed to hear "decathlon" pronounced as "decathalon" by the *pronouncer* at a children's spelling bee. The poor child was duly misled and eliminated. Similarly some Saint Louis relatives of mine used to refer to the "Missoura Athaletic Club."

Comment: @Neeku looks like that is a specialized case of what I was looking for; I apologize for the horrible example I originally included.

Comment: @BrianDonovan those are much better examples than my original one; I might steal them!

Comment: BTW, it's not **letters** that are being inserted. Letters can only be written, never spoken; it's **vowels** -- real sounds pronounced by real vocal tracts of real humans -- that are inserted. And not just any vowel, either. Virtually always in English it's a shwa that's inserted.

Comment: @JohnLawler At the time I wrote the question I wasn't sure whether the term I was looking for referred to letter insertion or sound insertion, which is why I said, "additional letters or sounds," but I think many people would also write the extra letters.  Is there a different term for inserting additional letters when you write a word, other than *misspelling*?

Comment: Well, it's always vowels, whether it's letters or sounds. And while the sounds are identical, the letters aren't, since there usually isn't a standard spelling for representing epenthetic vowels, and no spelling for shwa anyway.

Comment: Ay, @JohnLawler, in both of the examples I offered, the extraneous vowel sound was indeed (as I spell it) schwa /ə/ (although, curiously, single *a,* even when stressed or pitch-accented, denotes /ʌ/ in the double-vowel system of orthography for the Algonquian language *Ojibwemowin.)*

Comment: Yes, but this is because that's Ojibwe orthography, not English. What's transcribed as _a_ in Hindi and Sanskrit is also pronounced /ʌ/. Nothing new.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple insertion is [*epenthesis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epenthesis); swapping, [*metathesis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metathesis_%28linguistics%29).

Comment: Off-topic: Your rep and the -99-ending badge count are being envied!!

Comment: @tchrist that was fast; thanks!  Bonus points for also mentioning swapping.

Comment: And vowels that have been inserted by epenthesis are ***epenthetic vowels***. The automnemonic for _epenthesis_ is _epenethesis_, and the one for _metathesis_ is _methatesis_. See also _haplogy, pocope, apocop,_ and _syncpe_.

Answer (score -1):

I think the word you are looking for is **paragoge.** This means "the addition of a sound or a group of sounds at the end of a word."

I like Brian Donovan's example, decathlon, and would add that another common example is "rig-a-marole" for **rigmarole.**
Off topic: The opposite mistake, taking away a sound that is needed, is called **hyphaeresis.**